# MDX Slicer axis dimension properties

Tags: mdx

How do I request dimension properties on the slicers axis / WHERE section of an MDX request. I need the CHILDREN_CARDINALITY property of a member. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  But, you can create a Set in WITH section using that property, something like this:

```
WITH
SET [Set Filter]  As Filter({Dimension.Members}, Dimension.CurrentMember.Properties("PROPERTY_NAME") = "Value")
Select {} On 0, {} On 1 FROM [Cube]
WHERE ([Set Filter])
```